# TFS 2010 Team Web Access - continuous authentication prompts appear and page never fully loads

Tags: tfs, remote-access, firewall

at my company we have a number of clients and partners accessing our TFS 2010 SharePoint project portal and Team Web Access site over the Internet (https mostly but in this case http). For most of them everything works fine. For **one** client though, the following happens:

1. Authentication prompt appears when accessing either the project portal or Team Web Access
2. User types in username and password
3. The page loads half-way with text, but without CSS or images loaded.
4. Prompt appears again, even if "Remember password" is checked in the browser dialogue (IE8)
5. User tries the same procedure 10-20 times but gives up, resulting in an incomplete page load with no CSS or images.

In our attempts to remedy this we have opened ports 80, 8080, 443, 1443, 8000 but the errors still occurs for this specific client.

We thought it might be related to port 8080 causing firewall problems, so we moved Team Web Access to port 80, but the problem is still there.

Why could this be happening? The client certainly wants to know but I'm afraid I have no good answer yet.

Comment: Any way you can go to the client site and run Fiddler to see what's happening on the network?

Answer (score 1):

Try change Internet Options > Advanced > Under the security section > uncheck "Enabled integrated Windows Authentication".

Comment: Hi Morten, thank you for your feedback. The client tried this but unfortunately it didn't help. Do you have any more suggestions that might work?

Comment: You could try using another browser, to see how that works. I sounds like something is broken on the specific browser installation.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your Team Web Access URL to the Intranet Zone sites list. `Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet > Sites > Advanced`. There is a security setting that says 'Automatic logon only in Intranet zone'.

Also, take a look in `Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage Windows Credentials` and make sure that an incorrect password is not saved for the site.